# Getting OSError: [WinError 87] and Type Error: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm following along a Packt book called Python Web Scraping - Second Edition with reference code from here https://github.com/kjam/wswp/tree/master/code/chp4
and I keep getting the error in the title of my post.

The code does work on macOS and from what I've gathered around, the issue may be with fork vs spawn difference between Windows & Linux. I'm new to multiprocessing and can't figure out what and where I need to change for it to run correctly on Windows. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn") to no avail based on some digging here on SO.

```
import multiprocessing
import time



def threaded_crawler_rq(start_url, link_regex, user_agent='wswp', proxies=None,
                        delay=3, max_depth=4, num_retries=2, cache={}, max_threads=10, scraper_callback=None):
    """ 
     Comments
    """



def mp_threaded_crawler(*args, **kwargs):
    """ create a multiprocessing threaded crawler """
    processes = []
    num_procs = kwargs.pop('num_procs')
    if not num_procs:
        num_procs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    for _ in range(num_procs):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=threaded_crawler_rq,
                                       args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        proc.start()
        processes.append(proc)

    # wait for processes to complete
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from chp4.alexa_callback import AlexaCallback
    from chp3.rediscache import RedisCache
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Multiprocessing threaded link crawler')
    parser.add_argument('max_threads', type=int, help='maximum number of threads',
                        nargs='?', default=5)
    parser.add_argument('num_procs', type=int, help='number of processes',
                        nargs='?', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('url_pattern', type=str, help='regex pattern for url matching',
                        nargs='?', default='$^')
    par_args = parser.parse_args()

    AC = AlexaCallback()
    AC()
    start_time = time.time()

    mp_threaded_crawler(AC.urls, par_args.url_pattern, cache=RedisCache(),
                        num_procs=par_args.num_procs, max_threads=par_args.max_threads)
    print('Total time: %ss' % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threaded_crawler_with_queue.py", line 49, in <module>
    num_procs=par_args.num_procs, max_threads=par_args.max_threads)
  File "threaded_crawler_with_queue.py", line 22, in mp_threaded_crawler
    proc.start()
  File "C:\Users\iR9\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\iR9\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\iR9\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\iR9\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\iR9\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

C:\Users\iR9\Desktop\wswp\code>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\iR9\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\iR9\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Comment: Please upgrade your code to a [mcve].

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thank you for the suggestion. I have removed all the code that I can that doesn't add anything new to the original error.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, you also need to include the error you are getting with the provided code, with complete stacktrace.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I updated the post with the output error.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows at least, arguments that you provide to the function that would be run in a worker process are passed to that process via an IPC channel under the hood.

As such, you cannot pass unpicklable objects in `args` and `kwargs` to `multiprocessing.Process()`.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Sasha\Documents>pip install ipdb
<...>
(venv) C:\Users\Sasha\Documents>ipdb3 t.py
> c:\users\sasha\documents\t.py(1)<module>()
----> 1 import multiprocessing
      2 import time
      3

ipdb> b 23
Breakpoint 1 at c:\users\sasha\documents\t.py:23
ipdb> c
> c:\users\sasha\documents\t.py(23)mp_threaded_crawler()
     22                                        args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
1--> 23         proc.start()
     24         processes.append(proc)

ipdb> p args
(['http://google.com', 'http://youtube.com', 'http://facebook.com', 'http://baidu.com', <...>
ipdb> p kwargs
{'cache': <chp3.rediscache.RedisCache object at 0x000000000560F780>, 'max_threads': 5}
ipdb> import pickle
ipdb> pickle.dumps(kwargs)
*** TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

Objects aren't unpicklable for no reason. Usually, that means that whatever they represent (like a synchonization primitive or a network connection) is inherenly process-local so it makes no sense to try to pass it to another process.

Comment: So how should I rewrite the code to fix the problem?

Comment: @M4cJunk13 The problematic object represents a Redis cache. So you should open it in the worker instead of passing or something, I guess.